# Switch from panel into tabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, tabs, jpanel

I have a tabbedPane that contain 2 JPanel.

```
tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

tabbedPane.addTab("Main", null, mainPanel, "Does nothing");
    tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);

tabbedPane.addTab("Report", null, reportPanel, "Still does nothing");
```

I'm in the first panel and after an operation i would pass to second pannel (Main -> Report).

How can i do it?

Comment: Nizil already gave the correct answer, but if you need change tabs automatically after completing something in the first (a wizard style dialog?), it is quite possible that you should be using [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`JTabbedPane#setSelectedIndex(int index)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setSelectedIndex%28int%29)